# Need help trying to figure out Android intent constructor

Tags: android

I am trying to learn how to develop Android applications. I am reading on the Android Developers Guide site http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html, specifically about Explicit vs. Implicit Intents. One of the examples for an explicit intent looks like this:

```
// Executed in an Activity, so 'this' is the Context
// The fileUrl is a string URL, such as "http://www.example.com/image.png"
Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
downloadIntent.setData(Uri.parse(fileUrl));
startService(downloadIntent);
```

The constructor `Intent(this, DownloadService.class)` looks like this public constructor in the Android APIs ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html ):

```
public  Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

The Intent constructor documentation states:

> Create an intent for a specific component. All other fields (action, data, type, class) are null, though they can be modified later with explicit calls. This provides a convenient way to create an intent that is intended to execute a hard-coded class name, rather than relying on the system to find an appropriate class for you; see setComponent(ComponentName) for more information on the repercussions of this.

What I am trying to figure out is, what is the "this" in the constructor? I mean, I know what "this" is in general (the current instance of your activity), but what is it in this specific content? In the comments, it says "Executed in an Activity, so 'this' is the Context", but what is the "Context"? It isn't one of the five pieces of information that make up an intent (Component Name, Action, Data, Category, Extras, Flags).  I know the "DownloadService.class" parameter is the Component Name, so I'm just trying to figure out what it is.

Comment: Well `Activity` extends `Context`. From the docs `It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to figure out is, what is the "this" in the constructor?

It is an instance of some subclass of `Context`, such as an `Activity`.

> It isn't one of the five pieces of information that make up an intent (Component Name, Action, Data, Category, Extras, Flags).

No, but the combination of the `Context` and the Java class is enough to build the `ComponentName`. A `ComponentName` is a combination of an application ID and the fully-qualified class name to the component in that application. The Java class can provide the fully-qualified class name; the `Context` is where `ComponentName` pulls in the application ID (in this case, for your own application).

Comment: Why is it needed, then? According to the Android Developers guide, only those 5 pieces of information are needed to create an intent.

Comment: @Brian: "Why is it needed, then?" -- as I wrote, you are using the combination of the `Context` and the Java class to build the `ComponentName`. The `ComponentName` is what makes the `Intent` explicit. "I know the "DownloadService.class" parameter is the Component Name" -- no, it is not. It is the Java class that implements the component, but it is not the `ComponentName` Java object used by the `Intent`.

Comment: Ah ... Ok, I think I've got it now. So, when the documentation says "This field of the Intent is a ComponentName object, which you can specify using a fully qualified class name of the target component, including the package name of the app.", instead of writing "com.example.ExampleActivity" I can just write "this, ExampleActivity.class"?

Comment: @Brian: Well, not exactly. A field is a field, and it holds one Java object. The field that you cite holds a `ComponentName`, not a `String`. Under the covers, the `Intent` constructor you are discussing creates the `ComponentName` for you out of the `Context` and the Java class. You are welcome to populate the `ComponentName` in the `Intent` by other means.

Comment: Got it ... thanks. As a side question, is your book available in a physical copy, or just digital? I've seen it recommended before and have been thinking about getting it.

Comment: @Brian: "is your book available in a physical copy, or just digital?" -- it clocks in at over 3,300 pages nowadays, and so it is only available in digital format. You're welcome to print the PDF, but if a tree walks up and smacks you for using so much paper, don't blame me. :-)

Comment: Yikes ... digital it is.